# Magento only the last event is executed

Tags: magento

i have a small problem. I have register two events, but only the last was alwas called,
can someone help me

```
<!-- Events -->
<events>
  <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
    <observers>
      <save_after>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>XXX_testr_Model_Observer_OrderObserver</class>
        <method>orderSubmitEvent</method>
      </save_after>
    </observers>
  </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>

  <customer_save_after>
    <observers>
      <XXX_testr_observer_observer>
        <type>singleton</type> 
        <class>XXX_testr_Model_Observer_Observer</class>
        <method>customerSaveEvent</method>
      </XXX_testr_observer_observer>
    </observers>
  </customer_save_after>                
</events>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it could possibly be an observer name clash, try namespacing it to be unique

try changing:

save_after

to:

sdz_wawiconnector_observer_save_after

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usage, you might have more luck working with the controller thrown event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I can tell that your xml is valid.

Check such things:

1. duplicates of observer names (may be save_after or XXX_testr_observer_observer have already exist)
2. Look to the section, where you put these observers and there you want them to be executed. For example, you put them into frontend section, so customer_save_after will not run in admin.
3. Make a check if some other observer (from 3rd party extensions) do not crashes before. Or, for example, it can use 'die' in its code.
4. Check if some other extension rewrites core model/controller (or your store have such rewrite in app/code/local/Mage/.. section) and doesn't have event dispatcher in its code